# C# Dataset error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net, dataset

I have the following code:

```
namespace Company.Project.DataProvider
{    
    partial class MyDataSet
    {
        partial class MyDataTable
        {
        }
    }
}

namespace Company.Project.DataProvider.MyDataSetTableAdapters
{
    public partial class MyTableAdapter
    {
        public int CommandTimeout
        {
            set
            {
                for (int i = 0; (i < this.CommandCollection.Length); i = (i + 1))
                {
                    if ((this.CommandCollection[i] != null))
                    {
                        this.CommandCollection[i].CommandTimeout = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ObjectDataSource1_ObjectCreating
        (object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        Company.Project.DataProvider.MyDataSetTableAdapters.MyTableAdapter =  
            (Company.Project.DataProvider.MyDataSetTableAdapters.MyTableAdapter)
              e.ObjectInstance;
        // Set command timeout to 2 minutes
        adapter.CommandTimeout = 120;
    }
}
```

When I run above code, I receive the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Company'
>   could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

What is wrong in my code?

---

Now that,I receive the following error.

```
CS1061: 'CariPeriyot.Rapor.TEST_TumRaporlar' does not contain a definition 
for 'CommandCollection' and  no extension method 'CommandCollection' 
accepting a first argument of type 'CariPeriyot.Rapor.TEST_TumRaporlar' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 7:         set
Line 8:         {
Line 9:           for (int i = 0; (i < this.CommandCollection.Length); i = (i + 1))
Line 10:           {
Line 11:              if ((this.CommandCollection[i] != null))
```

Comment: Which line do you get that error on?

Comment: Is it a single file? Different files in the same project? Different libraries?

Answer (score 3):

`Company.Project.DataProvider.MyDataSetTableAdapters.MyTableAdapter` refers to a class, not a variable, hence the assignment fails.

Try:

`Company.Project.DataProvider.MyDataSetTableAdapters.MyTableAdapter foo = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code:

```
Company.Project.DataProvider.MyDataSetTableAdapters.MyTableAdapter =  
   (Company.Project.DataProvider.MyDataSetTableAdapters.MyTableAdapter)
    e.ObjectInstance;
```

With:

```
Company.Project.DataProvider.MyDataSetTableAdapters.MyTableAdapter adapter =  
   (Company.Project.DataProvider.MyDataSetTableAdapters.MyTableAdapter)
    e.ObjectInstance;
```

Comment: @leppie: However, I have used the rest of his code to figure out the right object name :)

Comment: @leppie: If you think it is an accomplishment to answer such a question, I will gladly delete my answer ;)

Comment: No, I dont think of it as an accomplishment. I dont understand why you simply repeated my answer...

Comment: @leppie: I didn't meant to steal your answer. As you see I did not use the explanation you build your answer on. However, I've added something to it which is the right object name. You and I may not think that thing has a value. But OP may do.